# Securing A PHP Page receiving AJAX POST and GET requests

Tags: php, ajax, security, pdo

I have an application where i have one class file that handles all of my ajax POST and GET requests.

- ajax.class.php

Can anyone recommend a solution that would block that page from receiving any Malicious or Unauthorized requests. I am already using PDO prepared statements and also using a PurifyHTML Class to clean some of the user input containing HTML. My main concern is with someone viewing my source and seeing that all my form actions are set to "/classes/ajax.class.php" and then trying to send unwanted requests to it.

```
if($_GET['ajax'] == 'callerIdInfo'){
    $number = $_GET['number'];
    ... [RECORD TO DB]
}

if($_POST['ajax'] == 'submitTicket'){
   ... [MORE FUNCTIONS]
}

etc etc..
```

Comment: "Use authentication" would probably be the best answer here, but this question is *way* too broad.

Comment: All users are authenticated. I have a 'Protect' class in place that checks the session for the correct user level, but i was just looking for some extra security. I think I am going to use tokens on each form

Comment: That, and/or just `include/require` a file from inside another.

Comment: That's a good start. Let me pose it to you this way: do you think Facebook cares if you view their page source and look at where their forms are `POST`ing to? No, because they have the proper authentication procedures in place, among other things.

Comment: @esqew I haven't deployed my application yet, Im in testing phases looking for vulnerabilities cause I sure as hell don't want to care either

Comment: For more in-depth security-related help with your problem I'd suggest heading over to [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com). They probably won't help you at the code level but they may make some suggestions as to what you can do to prevent these forged requests.

Comment: Another Stack resource is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep things simple.

You can define a strong encrypted key in your applicatio:

```
define('TOKEN_KEY', '%b&*0D0/V%)^l76L_O4(eWm6R&tv3^d916PV+"m_}te8On8L0a4-bd1');
```

Put it in a `config.php` file for example

```
include('config.php');
try {

    $token = $_POST['token'];
    if ($_POST['token']!==TOKEN_KEY) {
        throw new Exception('You Are not autorized '.$token);
    }

    //continue execution
    include('/classes/ajax.class.php');


} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log('Error!',  $e->getMessage(), "\n");
    //stop execution exit 
}
```

So instead of just generating a session and checking if it is empty , you can implement something like the above yet very simple.

You can wrap the logic into functons

```
function get_token() {
    return TOKEN_KEY;
}


function token_isvalid($token) {
    return $token===TOKEN_KEY;
}
```

usage

```
    if (!token_isvalid($_POST['token'])) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
```

Comment: I guess you mean `return $token===TOKEN_KEY;` (one "=" too much) in function token_isvalid($token)...right?
[PHP Operators - Comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Hehe...true, you did not tag me. =)

Answer (score 0):

I added this function to my main class:

```
function generateToken() {

    if(empty($_SESSION['form']['token']))
        $_SESSION['form']['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));

}
```

Then add this to my forms and to generate a hidden token for each.

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form']['token']; ?>"/>
```

Then check for the token in each request

```
if (empty($_POST['token'])){
  return false;
} else {
    // Do AJAX
    if($_POST['ajax'] == 'submitTicket'){
    ... 
    }

}
```

Comment: It's important to note that a motivated malicious actor could MiTM your users and watch the content of their page in order to retrieve their token, which then could be leveraged to make these fake requests you're concerned about. (You may also want to invest some time into researching SSL/TLS.)

Comment: Thanks looking at some TLS questions now...

Comment: you need to change the form token with each new form. also give it a timeout. like make it invalid after a useful time of seconds. read about CSRF, the problems it ships with is similar to what you would like to prevent: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)